# Where did Papa Smurf learn his magic?

Tags: magic, wizards, smurfs

Aside from being the Smurf's beloved and patriarchal leader, Papa Smurf has proven himself to be an accomplished Wizard; even Mother Nature and Father Time respect his magic game.  Little is known about where he learned all of his magical knowledge and skill, however.

Is there any history or legend as to where and how he built his magical knowledge?

Comment: Grandpa Smurf was a magician too, and he taught Papa Smurf everything he knows, so I think he must have learned it from his father initially? He also seems to be an active participant of the general magical community—he’s friends with human sorcerers like Alderic (*Les schtroumpfeurs de flûte*) and a great admirer of Merlin (cartoon canon).

Comment: @melissa_boikois that canon? I can see Grandpa training him in some stuff, but Papa seems far more powerful....though oddly enough, not _As_ powerful as the naturally magical Baby. Any references, or at least screen shots?

Comment: nope, just speculation (that's why I posted as a comment and not answer).